# Add a dynamic field to a MySQL table based on a functions value

Tags: php, mysql

Hay, I have a table a products which has a 'cost_price' field. When a user sees this field it has been put through a function in PHP which returns a new value (basically adds 20% and then removes a certain percent based on a user's registration level). Let's say this function is called 'final_price()'. This takes and outputs a float.

I want to preform a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `member_price` BETWEEN `x` AND `y`
```

However the 'member_price' field doesn't exist, this will be the value from the 'final_price' function. So the 'cost_price' would be run through the 'final_price' function and be put into the 'member_price' field.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you are calculating the price in PHP instead of SQL directly?

Comment: This can all be achieved in MySQL, it'll be faster and easier to maintain

Comment: The function takes values from other tables an additional 2 tables `users` table and `brands` table. We have a `user` level which adds different a % to the price, and we have a `brand markup` which adds a markup based on the brand.

Comment: Doesn't look too complicated, are you sure you don't want to do it with SQL directly?

Comment: Why not? If it works faster and is easier to maintain like jake says.

Comment: jakenoble is saying the same thing as I am.

Comment: sorry, how would i go about doing this in a SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can give you an idea of how to make the calculation in sql:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE 
cost_price * 1.2 *  
(SELECT user_level * $some_coefficient FROM users WHERE user_id = $uid) 
between x and y
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the filter needs to be applied after the calculation, so your options are

- do the calculation inside the database server
- retrieve all rows, then calculate and filter in the frontend.

While technically you could feed the calculation results back into the database and select from them, I think that would be a really bad solution, and I have to flog myself for even mentioning it.